# Supposed to send a welcome message when someone joins but nothing happens

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
import discord
import os
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member): 
    if member.guild.name == 'Bot Test Server':  
        await client.get_channel(927272717227528262).send("https://tenor.com/view/welcome-to-hell-lucifer-morningstar-tom-ellis-lucifer-welcome-gif-18399120")
    else:
        return
```

Everything is set correctly and it should send the message, but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you enabled Intents?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled Intents

Comment: Do you have multiple `on_member_join` events?

Comment: No only the one

Comment: can you show how you initialize the discord client?

Answer (score 1):

Why you didn't initialize client? and I fixed your code since it's not clear nor doesn't look like from dpy docs

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member): 
    if member.guild.name == 'Bot Test Server':
        channel = client.get_channel(927272717227528262)
        await channel.send("https://tenor.com/view/welcome-to-hell-lucifer-morningstar-tom-ellis-lucifer-welcome-gif-18399120")
    else:
        return

client.run('')
```